# Android.view.WindowManager $ BadTokenException:

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am developing a Screen Lock application
It works fine on some devices, but in some cases I get this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3209)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:150)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
>       Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 
>         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:609)
>         at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
>         at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>         at com.ingilizceogren.sloth.KilitUygulamasi.KilitUygulamasiKontrol.setLockScreenToWindow(KilitUygulamasiKontrol.java:150)
>         at com.ingilizceogren.sloth.KilitUygulamasi.KilitUygulamasiKontrol.lock(KilitUygulamasiKontrol.java:90)
>         at com.ingilizceogren.sloth.KilitUygulamasi.KilitUygulamasiServisi.onStart(KilitUygulamasiServisi.java:63)
>         at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:459)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3170)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your activity is running, use

```
if(mActivity != null && !mActivity.isFinishing())
```

to check when you call your  `com.ingilizceogren.sloth.KilitUygulamasi.KilitUygulamasiKontrol.setLockScreenToWindow()`